# Caching data in fields in form input

Tags: php, javascript

I have a small form with two fields: login + password.
I would like when a user gets connected by entering valid credentials, and when he comes back for new login, to cache data in form fieds. Like when we go to the gmail interface and find the email address and password are already in the fields and we just have to submit.

This does not work on my website.

Comment: Do you mean the effect as achieved by `autocomplete="on"`?

Comment: this is kinda what server side sessions are meant for

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 [local storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) or [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) in PHP. But, I wouldn't store user information (especially username and password) on the client-side.

Alternatively you can save a cookie saying that the user is logged in. And when they visit, grab the username from your database and display it in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever store a password anywhere in the raw. People using hashing algorithms so not even the staff at the company can get the password.

Save a cookie by all means. Make sure that they need to access a page periodically and perhaps up to a maximum time. Have a policy as to the number of incorrect password entries before either prevent access to the account or a period of time before another check can be performed. Check that cookie against the database (checking IP address etc) to try to ensure it is valid. Encrypt that cookie so it cannot be guessed.

Do not even (here I disagree with William) fill in username fields by default. It may be a public machine.

Answer (score -1):

you can save login/pass in cookies of web browser. But i think that browsers offer save password because they understand what fields you fill, maybe if input element on your form will be 'login' and 'password' or something that browser can associate with login form, that it can save creditinals of client